# Is possible to have List<T> property with get, which does not allow to add items to it directly?

Tags: c#, properties

I have following class

```
public class Workflow
{
    public List<IActivity> Activities { get; } = new List<IActivity>();
    public void Add(IActivity activity)
    {
        Activities.Add(activity);
    }
}
```

Now, Idea is that Activities could be added only using Add method. But I also need to be able to read them, so I can execute them.

Now look at the program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var workflow = new Workflow();

        //I want this to work and it works
        workflow.Add(new UploadVideoActivity());

        //I want this to not work, but it works.
        workflow.Activities.Add(new UploadVideoActivity());
        WorkflowEngine.Run(workflow);
    }
}
```

Am I able to create `List<T>` property, that allows us to add items to it only using the method, but can be read from the class?

Comment: Suggested reading: **[Guidelines for Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/guidelines-for-collections)**.  You could maintain a local (private) `List<T>` but expose a `ReadOnlyCollection<t>` which you return from that property

Comment: What about removing items, or replacing items?  Should it be possible to do other sorts of modifications to the list directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `List<IActivity>` internally but expose it as `IReadOnlyList<IActivity>` property so it cannot be modified from outside your class:

```
public class Workflow
{
    private readonly List<IActivity> activities = new();
    public IReadOnlyList<IActivity> Activities => activities;
    public void Add(IActivity activity)
    {
        activities.Add(activity);
    }
}
```